# A Subclass delegate function not called without adding it to the super class and overriding it at every subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, inheritance, overriding

I'm facing issues when changing the scheme to release 
where each subclass delegate function such as 
**scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)** 
or
**tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)**

not getting called at the subclass unless it's **overridden** or it's **different scheme** than release scheme

**Note that i'm using Xcode 10.3 in release mode**

i've tried adding the function to the super class and overridden it at the subclass which worked as expected but it was working yet this is not good solution since the app is huge and it's will affect lots of areas

Working code:

A- Super Class

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { }
```

B- SubClass

```swift
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { 
    print("Called successfully") //Called successfully
}
```

what it used working before changing the scheme to release:
B- SubClass

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { 
    print("Called successfully") //Called successfully
}
```

What i want is to use the subclass delegate function without adding empty function to override to the superclass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't make the super class conform to the delegate protocol or implement a specific protocol for the subclasses to implement that is being called from the delegate method in the superclass.